# Defining a style with android parent style

Tags: android, api

I've found here on SO how to basically mix my own style with android's.
This was:

```
<style name="something" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

But Android Studio gives me a warning saying that parent requires API 11, and unfortunately I need my program to run on API 7. Is there any way to bypass this issue?